# Proving that V is a K-vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove that $V$ with addition and scalar multiplication defined is a vector space over $K$.

$V=K^{\mathbb{N}}=\{(a_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}= (a_1,a_2,...,a_n,...)/a_i \in K \quad \forall i\in \mathbb{N} \}$, the set of all sequences of elements of $K$ (where $K$ is any field).

$+  :   (a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}+ (b_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}= (a_i+b_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$

$\cdot :k.(a_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}= (k.a_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$

I think that I have to prove that:

a) $(V, +)$ is abelian group

b) The group action $ \cdot $ which satisfies:

i) $\ a(v+w)=av+aw \quad \forall \ a \in K;\ \forall \ v,w \in V $

ii) $\ (a+b)v=av+bv \quad \forall \ a,b \in K;\ \forall \ v \in V $

iii)$\ 1.v=v \quad \forall \ v \in V$

iv)$\ (a.b)v=a(b.v) \quad \forall \ a,b \in K;\ \forall \ v \in V$

Since $K$ is a field, $(K,+)$ must be an abelian group, so I think I kinda see why $(V,+)$ must be an abelian group, but don't know how to actually prove it. Same goes to the other items, I would really appreciate some help.

The item iii) is the only one that I see more obvious, I would say that if I take k=1 then $\cdot :1.(a_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}= (1.a_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}=(a_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ but I'm not even sure about that one.

**EDIT:** I was really confused about the notation but now I *think* I get it, so I tried again but I'm likely to have a lot of mistakes:

a) Let's first prove that $(V,+)$ is an abelian group:

1) Since $(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}+ (b_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}= (a_i+b_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ then $(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}+ (b_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}+(c_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}= (a_i+b_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}+(c_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(b_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}+(c_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}=(b_i+c_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ therefore $(a_i+b_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}+(c_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}=(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}+(b_i+c_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$

2) "There is a neutral element $e \in V$ such that $a+e=e+a=a \quad \forall a \in V$". Since $K$ is a field $0 \in K$, then there must exist a sequence $(e_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}=0, \quad 0 \in K, \ e_i \in V$. Then $(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}+ (e_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}= (a_i+0)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}=(a_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}=(0+a_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$. Let's supossed that there's another neutral element and let's call it $(e'_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$. Therefore $(e'_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}=(e'_i+e_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}=(e_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ so $(e_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is the only neutral element.

3)Let's call $(d_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}=((-a)_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$. Then $(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}+ (-a_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}= (a_i-a_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}=(e_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$, so for every $a_i$ there is a $-a_i$ which is it's inverse.

4)$(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}+ (b_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}= (a_i+b_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}=(b_i+a_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}=(b_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}+ (a_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$

b.i) Let's define $(c_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}=(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}+ (b_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}= (a_i+b_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$. By hypothesis: $k.(c_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}= (k.c_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ therefore $k.(c_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}=k.(a_i+b_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}=(k(a_i+b_i))_{i\in \mathbb{N}}=k.(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}+k.(b_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ with $k \in K$.

ii) If $k=m+n, \quad k,m,n \in K$, then $(m+n).(c_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}= ((m+n).c_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}=(m.c_i+n.c_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}=m.(c_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}+n.(c_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$

iii) already done

iv) $(m.n).(c_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}= n.(m.(c_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}})= n.(m.c_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$

Comment: Well if you have a field $K$ then for any $i$ we have that $a_i + b_i = b_i + a_i$, thus it works for any two sequences $a_1,a_2,a_3, \cdots $ and $b_1, b_2, b_3 , \cdots$.

Comment: To prove that $(V,+)$ is an abelian group, one must prove that $(V,+)$ satisfies the axioms of an abelian group (one of which, for example, is the existence of an inverse in $V$: let $(a_i)$ be an element of $V$, its inverse is $(-a_i)$...).

Comment: Please guys help I swear that I'm trying but I really don't understand it. I know that if $(v,+)$ is an abelian group it must satisfy that: 1) $(a+b)+c=a+(b+c) \quad \forall \ a,b,c \in V$ 2) There is a neutral element $e \in V$ such that $a+e=e+a=a \ \forall a \in V$ (a prove of that one could be that if I pick $e=0$ it satisfies that equation, but if V is the sequence of ALL elements of K, how do I know which elements K has? How do I know that $0\in V$?) 3) The one @Learning wrote and 4) $a+b=b+a$ which rubikscube09 already prove. I think that the problem is that I don't actually +

Comment: understand what's V. I mean, if V is the sequence of all elements of K, then wouldn't be $a_i=b_i=c_i$ since all of them are the sequence of all elements of K?

Comment: @cor1.1.29, don't call other people _guys_ because many of them are professors.

Comment: How would your proof look for, e.g., $M_{mn}(\mathbb C)_{\mathbb R}$, where the matrix coefficients/entries are complex, while scalars are real (exclusively). ? (:

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to offend anyone, I will take that into account for now on :) Thank you!